# La intalación de composer no encuentra las rutas

Tags: php7, xampp, composer

Estoy usando XAMPP para el desarrollo en ambiente local y hace años que uso composer, pero también hace años que lo instalé por última vez, entonces recientemente he tenido que reinstalar toda mi PC (Windows 10) y el correspondiente XAMPP .. hasta ahí todo bien .. XAMPP funciona bien pero cuando trato de intslar composer por medio del instalador ofrecido para Windows la instalación aborta porque no encuentra las rutas a las librerías de PHP

```
The PHP exe file you specified did not run correctly:
F:\xampp\php\php.exe
The php.ini used by your command-line PHP is: F:\xampp\php\php.ini
A setting in your php.ini could be causing the problem: Either the
'extension_dir' value is incorrect or the dll does not exist.
Program Output:
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '\xampp\php\ext
\php_bz2.dll' - No se puede encontrar el módulo especificado.
in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '\xampp\php\ext
\php_curl.dll' - No se puede encontrar el módulo.....
```

Entonces me voy al phpinfo() y las librerías están cargadas correctamente para PHP, pero no entiendo porque entonces composer no las reconoce.

Por si sirve de algo, debo decir que estoy usando una versión portable de XAMPP una de las últimas con PHP 7.1.31

Answer (score 0):

nunca supe porque composer no encontraba las rutas... considerando que apache y php si las encontraban .. en todo caso, la solución definitiva que pude darle fue dejar de usar una versión portable y en ves de eso, usar una versión instalada que básicamente crea rutas físicas. a partir de ahí, composer corrió perfectamente.

Comment: he encontrado parte de la respuesta a mi pregunta pero no entiendo lo de instalar una versión no portable, os referís a wamp? Además wamp me da un error por tener php en el path pero sin él composer no funciona.
Gracias

Comment: Hola, debes añadir a la variable de entorno "PATH" la ruta donde está el archivo "php.exe". En Windows 10 abres el explorador de archivos, das clic derecho sobre "Este equipo", eliges "Propiedades", luego "Configuración avanzada del sistema", vas a la pestaña "Opciones avanzadas" y oprimes el botón "Variables de entorno", allí eliges la variable "Path" y le das a "Editar", en el cuadro de dialogo que se abre añades "C:\xampp\php" y aceptas en todas las ventanas que abriste. Lo ideal sería que editaras la variable "Path" del grupo "Variables del sistema".